# how to replace image path with image in textview, there are lots of image in single text view in offline mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Images are first downloaded using image url's in online mode from html page. All contents are also stored in `sqlite`. It is working fine when internet is present. `webview` is showing all text & images. But when internet is not present, text is showing but images are not displaying. My images are stored in files. I also have image path from that I can receive image but the problem is how i put that images in between `UITextview` using `UImageview`.

When I am using `UIImageview` and setting its frame all images are placed over one another and text are scrolled inside this.

So what I have to do to run text with many images in proper position in offline mode?